# How do these two constraints conflict?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm having problems tracking down some conflicting constraints.  The AutoresizingMask has been added for me, and the other constraint I added in an attempt to understand what is going on:

```
2015-09-26 22:27:14.959 Darkenss[26537:8462681] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc461fe9110 UICollectionView:0x7fc463090000.top == UIView:0x7fc461fc6620.topMargin + 302>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc461d3f820 h=--- v=--- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:[UIView:0x7fc461fc6620]-(0)-|>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc461fe9110 UICollectionView:0x7fc463090000.top == UIView:0x7fc461fc6620.topMargin + 302>
```

I don't see how these two constraints are actually in conflict.

The view hierarchy is:

```
<UIView: 0x7fc461fc6620; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461fc48a0>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461fd4f50; frame = (0 0; 600 600); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461fc7ea0>>
   | <UILabel: 0x7fc461fcba20; frame = (28 68; 300 48); text = 'Darkness AP'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fc461fcb910>>
   | <Darkenss.UIDescreteSliderWithCircles: 0x7fc461e477c0; frame = (28 124; 544 30); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461c2df00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461fb09b0>>
   | <UIButton: 0x7fc461e8c8e0; frame = (28 162; 93 128); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461c2c770>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e99bb0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d2ad70; frame = (0 6.5; 93 115); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d2af10>>
   | <UIButton: 0x7fc461e1ee60; frame = (129 162; 92 128); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461c2ccd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e1beb0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d38d50; frame = (0 6.5; 92 115); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d38ef0>>
   | <UIButton: 0x7fc461e20c10; frame = (229 162; 93 128); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461c2d1f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e372b0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d23ab0; frame = (0 6.5; 93 115); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d23c50>>
   | <UIButton: 0x7fc461e04d20; frame = (330 162; 92 128); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461c2d400>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e225a0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d2a9a0; frame = (0 6.5; 92 115); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d43d80>>
   | <UIButton: 0x7fc461e31e20; frame = (430 162; 81 128); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461e99d00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e31cd0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d2c750; frame = (0 6.5; 81 115); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d1e660>>
   | <UIButton: 0x7fc461e374f0; frame = (16 97.5; 145.5 128); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e34cb0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d20da0; frame = (0 0; 145.5 128); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d47ed0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461e55d50; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e3d850>>
   |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x7fc461d20f40; frame = (0 55.5; 27.5 17.5); text = 'Run
 Darkness
Cycle'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fc461d212f0>>
   | <UIButton: 0x7fc461e2d510; frame = (169.5 97.5; 181.5 128); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e60e10>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d51e50; frame = (0 0; 181.5 128); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d431f0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d3c3c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d3c560>>
   |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x7fc461d5c0e0; frame = (26.5 55.5; 128.5 17.5); text = ' Continue Combo '; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fc461d52250>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461fcda20; frame = (4 302; 592 294); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461fcd030>>
   | <UICollectionView: 0x7fc463090000; frame = (4 310; 367 353); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461e45640>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e3b3a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {367, 54}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc461e468d0>
   |    | <Darkenss.AddTrackerViewCell: 0x7fc4640217f0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 54 54); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc464020fc0>>
   |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7fc4640219c0; frame = (4 4; 46 46); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc464020e70>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc464024140; frame = (0 0; 46 46); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc4640200b0>>
   |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fc464022110; frame = (0 0; 54 54); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc4640228f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc464022270>>
   |    | <Darkenss.CounterArrayCellView: 0x7fc464032270; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (54.5 0; 258 53); alpha = 0; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc464032040>>
   |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fc4640324d0; frame = (0 0; 258 53); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc464032d10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc464032630>>
   |    |    |    | <Darkenss.CounterArrayView: 0x7fc464032d40; frame = (0 0; 94 102); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc464034b60>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7fc464033190; frame = (6 6; 82 0); text = 'Treasure'; hidden = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fc464033390>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <_UILabelContentLayer: 0x7fc461d84ee0> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    | <UICollectionView: 0x7fc46388e800; frame = (6 14; 82 82); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc4640340a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc464033ba0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {82, 81}> collection view layout: <Darkenss.CounterArrayLayout: 0x7fc464033960>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <Darkenss.DotView: 0x7fc461d7e190; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 40 40); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d7e530>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fc461d7e550; frame = (0 0; 40 40); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461d7ed90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d7e6b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d7e370; frame = (0 0; 40 40); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d7e510>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <Darkenss.DotView: 0x7fc461d82250; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (42 0; 40 40); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d821a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fc461d825d0; frame = (0 0; 40 40); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461d82e10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d82730>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d82430; frame = (0 0; 40 40); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d821c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <Darkenss.DotView: 0x7fc461d86290; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 41; 40 40); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d86610>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fc461d86630; frame = (0 0; 40 40); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461d86e80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d86790>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461d86470; frame = (0 0; 40 40); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461d86240>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc464032fd0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc464033170>>
   |    | <Darkenss.SmallCounterTrackerViewCell: 0x7fc461c90870; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 53; 108 56); clipsToBounds = YES; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461c8f970>>
   |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fc461c90a70; frame = (0 0; 188 96); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461eb1710>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461c8fb30>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461c90bd0; frame = (4 4; 88 88); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461c8fad0>>
   |    |    |    | <Darkenss.OffsetLabels: 0x7fc461c90eb0; frame = (96 4; 88 88); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461ca0570>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UITextView: 0x7fc462050200; frame = (0 0; 7 14); text = '10'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461c92170>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461c91af0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {7, 55}>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <<_UITextContainerView: 0x7fc461c92c00; frame = (0 0; 7 55); layer = <_UITextTiledLayer: 0x7fc461c92dd0>> minSize = {0, 0}, maxSize = {1.7976931348623157e+308, 1.7976931348623157e+308}, textContainer = <NSTextContainer: 0x7fc461c918f0 size = (7.000000,340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000); widthTracksTextView = YES; heightTracksTextView = NO>; exclusionPaths = 0x7fc461c00dc0; lineBreakMode = 0>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITextSelectionView: 0x7fc461c95070; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461c94fb0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UITextView: 0x7fc462052000; frame = (0 0; 9 14); text = '10'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc461c99480>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461c98df0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {9, 55}>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <<_UITextContainerView: 0x7fc461c9a270; frame = (0 0; 9 55); layer = <_UITextTiledLayer: 0x7fc461c9a440>> minSize = {0, 0}, maxSize = {1.7976931348623157e+308, 1.7976931348623157e+308}, textContainer = <NSTextContainer: 0x7fc461c98bd0 size = (9.000000,340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000); widthTracksTextView = YES; heightTracksTextView = NO>; exclusionPaths = 0x7fc461c00dc0; lineBreakMode = 0>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITextSelectionView: 0x7fc461c9c750; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461c9c690>>
   |    |    |    |    | <CAShapeLayer: 0x7fc461d7d7a0> (layer)
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461e44520; frame = (361.5 284; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461e3f7f0>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461fd19f0; frame = (3 292; 286 21); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461fd00c0>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461fdbec0; frame = (289 292; 23 21); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461fdb6e0>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7fc461fe1540; frame = (312 292; 285 21); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461fd1b90>>
   | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fc461fe6260; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461fe5f50>>
   | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fc461fe6cb0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc461fe5aa0>>
```

**Update:** I lost the hard drive that project was living on (but I have a backup that was only 45min old, so it'll all work out when I get a replacement...right?   I have hope at least).    However I have a very big clue.

I was calculating constraints and triggering layout in a KVO observer.   This observer was triggering before the view had a superview.   Skipping updates that happen before the view has a superview avoid this issue.   Thinking about that a little more and:

> 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:[UIView:0x7fc461fc6620]-(0)-|

Makes me think the -(0)- is "oh, and the view is zero height, thanks for playing" because said view has no superview and auto layout just doesn't want to deal with that mess.

Hopefully I can get the hardware back in working order early October and find out what is what!

Comment: are you doing this with the interface builder or programmatically?

Comment: Interface builder, at least the conflicting constraints.

Comment: Are you asking why they conflict or why there is an auto resizing constraint? What other constraints do you have on the collection view?

Comment: I would like to know why they conflict, the auto resizing one I think is "normal".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have forgotten to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` for some view that you added programmatically on which you are using constraints. That might explain the AutoresizingMask. Kindly check.

**UPDATE**:
Also, for this constraint:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc461fe9110 UICollectionView:0x7fc463090000.top == UIView:0x7fc461fc6620.topMargin + 302>
```

try changing `UIView:0x7fc461fc6620.topMargin` to  `UIView:0x7fc461fc6620.top`

I am guessing you haven't accounted for the margin while calculating your constant  "302"

Comment: The only view with translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints still YES is the "top level" view 0x7fc461fc6620.  If I turn that one off I'm not quite sure how to get it to place in it's superview.   IB won't let me place it relative to it's superview that's for sure.

Comment: Why is it so? What is its superview?

Comment: I think UIKit makes a _UIViewControllerWrapperView (very undocumented) as the superview at runtime.

Comment: I think the problem might be related to using Top Margin instead of Top while setting the top constraint for UICollectionView. Please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: Ok I'll try that.  Sadly I think I just lost a disk so I get to do exciting system restore things first.